# local Storage is not defined : JQuery

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using this piece of code inside a javascript function.
But when I run the application it gives a reference error that local Storage is not defined.

```
localStorage.setItem(result.key+authAppParams.application , result.key);
```

Why this occurs?
Why can't I use this inside a function?
Since it is a setItem and all the releated values are inside the method I cannot define the local Storage globally.

How can I avoid this issue and make this work?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) ?

Comment: What browser are you doing this on? Support is very good, but not absolutely universal. As Denys said, an [MCVE](/help/mcve) is important here.

Comment: What browser/what device? IIRC there were some issues with iPads/Safari a while back.

Comment: Side note: localStorage has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: !!tell user2674285 examplepls

Comment: There is nothing with localStorage & jQuery. I guess you are using a older browser that doesn't support localStorage. Check the same in a new updated browser.

Comment: Make sure you're not defining variable with name "localStorage" inside your function, it's shadowing real localStorage object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using localStorage you should always check for it first to make sure the browser has it implemented.

Something like this

```
if(window.localStorage) {
  // localStorage can be used
} else {
  // can't be used
}
```

Or, if this errors in your browser (which it may not), you can check with

```
if('localStorage' in window) {
  // localStorage can be used
} else {
  // can't be used
}
```

Should probably check for it early on in your code and only use it if it's available.

JS will always look on the global for a variable that it cannot find in the current context, so it looks as if it comes down to the browser not having it.

**Edit** Like everyone is commenting, localStorage and jQuery are completely separate

Comment: This is incorrect - that will throw an exception in modern browsers, see for example: http://crocodillon.com/blog/always-catch-localstorage-security-and-quota-exceeded-errors

Comment: You're saying the same thing I'm saying. Only difference is that you're saying wrap it in a try catch cause it will throw an exception if you use it. I'm saying check to see if you can use it and don't bother with the exception.

Comment: it wont hit the else block if it throws

Comment: Implementation details.... Like I said you don't even need the exception handling if you know you can't use it. Or remove the `else`

Comment: What? Then the code you've written is pointless. To do it correctly see the link I already posted

Comment: Maybe things have changed and browsers have stopped throwing on the error, but this solution works (at least in Chrome with local storage disabled) and returns `null`. I'll update the answer to include something from your blog