# Output Local Storage Values Via Console?

Tags: google-chrome, console, local-storage

I was wondering if it is possible to output with console using javascript some values which are stored inside chrome's Local Storage?

Comment: Like, `console.log(localStorage.getItem('myThing'));` ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that once I do that inside the console it will give me `localStorage is not defined` error..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641975/1136527

Comment: Alex McMillan Its the latest chrome version which supports the local storage

Comment: If you press F12 to bring up the console, and type `localStorage` what do you see?

Comment: its not defined if there are no values in the storage. I just tried your answer and it works but If I write localStorage on the other website where there are no values defined it will simply say that the localStorage is not defined which kind of makes sense now..

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just log your item:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('myItemName'));
```

Round-trip example:

```
const myThing = {
  name: 'Dave',
  age: 21
};

localStorage.setItem('myThing', JSON.stringify(myThing));
const myThingReturned = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myThing'));

console.log('Before:', myThing);
console.log('After:', myThingReturned);
```

Comment: Yes it works fine, but I think I asked my question in a wrong way as I want to get the values which are preset by the browser or the domain. As example if I open the Local storage on this website, I would like to retrieve `se:fkey` value from stackoverflow.com Local storage if that makes any sense

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
localStorage.getItem('{attribute name that you want to get}')
```

In your case you can get the value by using this

```
localStorage.getItem('se:fkey')
```

you can also just type `localStorage` in your chrome console to take a look at the available localstorage